# JBOSS EAP 7.3 : How to override jboss.as.jpa.providerModule for all server or server group?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss, eclipselink

I try to run the EAR file with multiply wars and jars on JBOSS EAP 7.3. On WAS server we used EclipseLink like JPA implementation for application. But JBoss uses Hibernate by default. We can change all `persistence.xml` files and set `<provider>` but maybe someone knows how to override the default persistence provider for the entire server or for the entire server group?
From logs:

> 2021-02-02 09:51:11,495 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-3) added (default provider) org.hibernate dependency to web.main.war (since 4 PU(s) didn't specify jboss.as.jpa.providerModule)

```
jboss.as.jpa.providerModule
```

Can we change this?

Comment: Do you use spring in your application?

Comment: @SternK unfortunately no. We have EJB , JSF, EclipseLink